# entity framework lazy loading null properties in child

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Using entity framwork with lazy loading - Have the following question on loading related entities when the entities 
are null.

Say I have two tables employee and employeedetails. Assume in the above case not all employee entries have an entry in the employeedetails table. 
If I want to look up a list of Employees

```
(from e in objectcontext.employees                                  
                              select new EmployeeEntity
                              {
                                  EmpID= e.EmployeeID,
                                  FirstName = e.FirstName,
                                  Address = e.employeedetails.Address
                              }).ToList();
```

EmployeeEntity is the data class into which we stuff the results.

The above code breaks if even one employee in the returned list 
does not have a entry in table employeedetails. **This is obvious since e.employeedetails will be null for those customers who do not have a details entry**

What is the best way to rewrite the above query?

Would something like this be acceptable ?

```
(from e in objectcontext.employees                                  
                              select new EmployeeEntity
                              {
                                  EmpID= e.EmployeeID,
                                  FirstName = e.FirstName,
     Address = e.employeedetails  == null ? "" :    e.employeedetails.Address,
                              }).ToList();
```

I am not clear on the efficiency of this above query - Would this statment do the null check at DB level?

Should I instead do an explicit include like

```
objectcontext.include("employeedetails")...
```

And then loop through the results to check for null?

Comment: Did you actually run into a null reference exception at runtime? In similar queries (with a select on a nullable reference object) I see EF produce outer joins and referenced property (`Address` in your case) is `null`.

Comment: Yes. I did run into a null reference at runtime - except they might not have been on a string field. In the actual code I retrieve quite a bunch of properties from the reference object. I think the null break might have been on a DateTime field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this statement would indeed perform a null check in the SQL query that is generated. Most likely, it will simply be a `NVL` or `COALESCE`.

That's the way you should be doing it.